# Не могу добавить приложение(django) в список INSTALLED_APPS,файл setting.py,помогите пожалуйста!

Tags: python, django

Подскажите пожалуйста,что надо написать в списке `INSTALLED_APPS`(файл `setting.py`) что бы сделать приложение инсталлированным(Ну если вкратце добавить в список INSTALLED_APPS)

Я уже это делал,мое приложение называлось articles и вот строка кода из списка `INSTALLED_APPS` - `'articles.apps.ArticlesConfig'`

Я начал тренироваться на другом проекте и создал новое приложение newsapp и так же добавляю его в `INSTALLED_APPS`,но возникает ошибка,вот строчка кода(добавление в список) -
`'newsapp.apps.ArticlesConfig'`

А вот ошибка -

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'articles'.
> Check that 'newsapp.apps.ArticlesConfig.name' is correct.

Помогите пожалуйста и да я новичок!

Код `apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig 

class ArticlesConfig(AppConfig): 
    name = 'articles' 
    erbose_name = 'БЛОГ'
```

Comment: покажи содержимое файла newsapp/apps.py

Comment: from django.apps import AppConfig


class ArticlesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'articles'
    verbose_name = 'БЛОГ'

Comment: лучше измени исходный вопрос, что бы код читался нормально

Comment: Окей,уже сделал

Comment: ты назвал приложение newsapp(так называется папка в которой оно находится) а в самом конфиге пишешь, что оно называется 'articles'. В итоге у тебя не совпадает название

Comment: Вот блин,такой тупой ошибки не вижу,просто эти строки кода скопировал из прошлого проекта и забыл поменять,огромное спасибо,вот только я заменил имя уже на newsapp,но у меня такая-же ошибка

Comment: Хотя нет,ошибка уже другого типа - ImportError: cannot import name 'Article' from 'newsapp.models' (D:\Python\Django\first\first\apps\newsapp\models.py)

Comment: сейчас ответ напишу

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: `erbose_name = 'БЛОГ'`

Answer (score 1):

либо просто поменять `name = 'articles'` `name = 'newsapp'` в файле `newsapp/apps.py`. Но что бы код выглядел логично тебе надо переименовать конфиг в файле newsapp/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class NewsappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'newsapp'
    verbose_name = 'БЛОГ'
```

и в settings.py поменять `'newsapp.apps.ArticlesConfig'` на `'newsapp.apps.NewsappConfig'`

Comment: Все сделал конфиг переименовал,написал в списке INSTALLED_APPS - 'newsapp.apps.NewsappConfig' и такая же ошибка,странно,ну у же днем когда проснусь буду думать над ошибкой,может быть ошибка в models.py?Еще раз показываю ту ошибку -  ImportError: cannot import name 'Article' from 'newsapp.models' (D:\Python\Django\first\first\apps\newsapp\models.py),самое главное в скобках,указан путь к models.py,ну вообщем потом буду думать,но все равно спасибо за помощь!

Comment: так теперь ошибка в другом файле в файле models.py надо бы его тоже выложить)

Comment: Не могу отправить текстом models.py(превышает лимит),а тут можно отправить фото(именно в комментах)?

Comment: можешь выложить на github и дать ссылку на приложение

Comment: Дать ссылку на все файлы приложения?

Comment: да, ссылку на приложение, что бы можно было посмотреть целиком

Comment: Блин,я не могу зайди на гитхаб,забыл пароль и не сохранил его,для нового аккаунта нужна новая почта,ну щас конечно могу сделать,но просто и так уже много времени прошло

Comment: лан ща попробую

Comment: я на сегодня уже все, теперь завтра)

Comment: Ну ок,потом напишу,спасибо за помощь и ксати повторю вопрос,а у вас есть ВК?

Comment: А какой у вас гит хаб?Вы просили скинуть приложение?Если есть время...

Comment: Все заработало!В файле admin.py где надо писать register и название класса,вместо News,я написал Article,из прошлого проекта,вот я не внимательный...

Comment: Замечательно, если заработало. Успехов